# Can't install libsqlite3-0-dbgsym: unmet dependencies

Tags: apt

I have troubles installing `libsqlite3-0-dbgsym` due to unmet dependencies, but the right dependency seems to be installed. Anyone have a suggestion?

```
mathieu@linda:~ $ sudo apt install libsqlite3-0-dbgsym 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsqlite3-0-dbgsym : Depends: libsqlite3-0 (= 3.31.1-4) but 3.31.1-4ubuntu0.2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

```
mathieu@linda:~ $ sudo apt list --installed | grep sqlite

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libsqlite3-0/focal-updates,focal-security,now 3.31.1-4ubuntu0.2 amd64 [installed]
libsqlite3-dev/focal-updates,focal-security,now 3.31.1-4ubuntu0.2 amd64 [installed]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: can you show `sudo apt update`

Comment: The package `libsqlite3-0-dbgsym` is not a Ubuntu repository package, and the package is very likely outdated & behind on patches (thus it can't deal with the patched libraries that are in Ubuntu repositories).  Your issue is your source of `libsqlite3-0-dbgsym` I suspect

Comment: `libsqlite3-0-dbgsym` is installable through the instructions found here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Debug%20Symbol%20Packages

Comment: was able to install with `aptitude` but I think I have weird versions now


mathieu@linda:~ $ apt list --installed | grep sqlite

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libsqlite3-0-dbgsym/focal,now 3.31.1-4 amd64 [installed]

libsqlite3-0/focal,now 3.31.1-4 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 3.31.1-4ubuntu0.2]

libsqlite3-dev/focal,now 3.31.1-4 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 3.31.1-4ubuntu0.2]

sqlite3/focal,now 3.31.1-4 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 3.31.1-4ubuntu0.2]